# List and ArrayList peculiar behavior in generics

Tags: java, list

Following code works fine while it should not `compile`.

I am not sure why assignment of a `List` to `String` is permitted.

It only happens to `List` interfaces. Changing to a `Array List` working fine as expected and it no longer compiles.

```
public class Test {
        public static <T extends List<Number>> T newList() {
            return null;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String s = newList();
        }
    }
```

Please help me understand this behavior.

Comment: There could possibly a subclass of String that implements the List interface (But this cannot happen as String is final)

Comment: Type inference doesn't take into account the final-ness of classes (like you can write `<T extends String>` more directly). So yes, what @user7 said.

Comment: @AndyTurner Nice. I did not know that. Unless this question is not a duplicate, could you make your comment an answer? Additionally, is there any documentation about that (maybe in the JLS)?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose in fact, the same wouldn't happen with ArrayList, because a class couldn't extend both ArrayList and String.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose it is a duplicate, it's just one of those nigh-on impossible to find ones, because it's hard to think of the search term.

Comment: @AndyTurner Exactly. I'm sure I read that here some time back

Comment: @ernest_k Good find!

Comment: @user7 I think tge explanation of yours is short and clear